# Super Gaussian fit

Tags: python, curve

I have to do study the laser beam profile. To this aim, I need to find a Super Gaussian curve fit for my data.
Super Gaussian equation:

```
I * exp(- 2 * ((x - x0) /sigma)^P)
```

where `P` takes into account the flat-top laser beam curve characteristics.

I started doing a simple Gaussian fit of my curve, in Python. The fit returns a Gaussian curve where the values of `I`, `x0` and `sigma` are optimized. (I used the function curve_fit) 
Gaussian curve equation:

```
I * exp(-(x - x0)^2 / (2 * sigma^2))
```

Now, I would like to do a step forward. **I would like to do the Super Gaussian curve fit** because I need to consider the flat-top characteristics of the beam. Thus, I need a fit which optimizes also the P parameter.

Does someone know how to do a Super Gaussian curve fit with Python?

I know that there is a way to do a Super Gaussian fit with wolfram mathematica which is not opensource. I do not have it. Thus, I would like also to know if someone knows an open source software thanks to which it is possible to do a Super Gaussian curve fit or to execute wolfram mathematica.

Thank you

Comment: Could you post your complete code? Also optimized w.r.t. which metric? MSE? Which packages are you using? Here are a bunch of optimizers: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html

Comment: The equation  I * exp(- 2 * ((x - x0) /sigma)^p) generates complex values for x<x0 . Instead write I * exp(- 2 * (abs(x - x0) /sigma)^p) .

Comment: thanks @JJacquelin I will try to do as you said

Answer (score 1):

Well, you would need to write a function that calculates a parameterized super-Gaussian and use that to model data, say with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.    As a lead author of LMFIT (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) which provides a high-level interface to fitting and curve-fitting, I would recommend trying that library. With that approach, your model function for a super-Gaussian and using to fit data might look like this:

```
import numpy as np  
from lmfit import Model   

def super_gaussian(x, amplitude=1.0, center=0.0, sigma=1.0, expon=2.0):
    """super-Gaussian distribution
    super_gaussian(x, amplitude, center, sigma, expon) =
        (amplitude/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma)) * exp(-abs(x-center)**expon / (2*sigma**expon))
    """
    sigma = max(1.e-15, sigma)
    return ((amplitude/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma))
            * np.exp(-abs(x-center)**expon / 2*sigma**expon))

# generate some test data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
y = super_gaussian(x, amplitude=7.1, center=4.5, sigma=2.5, expon=1.5)
y += np.random.normal(size=len(x), scale=0.015)

# make Model from the super_gaussian function
model = Model(super_gaussian)

# build a set of Parameters to be adjusted in fit, named from the arguments 
# of the model function (super_gaussian), and providing initial values
params = model.make_params(amplitude=1, center=5, sigma=2., expon=2)

# you can place min/max bounds on parameters
params['amplitude'].min = 0
params['sigma'].min = 0
params['expon'].min = 0
params['expon'].max = 100

# note: if you wanted to make this strictly Gaussian, you could set 
# expon=2  and prevent it from varying in the fit:
### params['expon'].value = 2.0
### params['expon'].vary = False

# now do the fit
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)

# print out the fit statistics, best-fit parameter values and uncertainties
print(result.fit_report())

# plot results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y, label='data')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This will print a report like

```
[[Model]]
    Model(super_gaussian)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 53
    # data points      = 101
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 0.02110713
    reduced chi-square = 2.1760e-04
    Akaike info crit   = -847.799755
    Bayesian info crit = -837.339273
[[Variables]]
    amplitude:  6.96892162 +/- 0.09939812 (1.43%) (init = 1)
    center:     4.50181661 +/- 0.00217719 (0.05%) (init = 5)
    sigma:      2.48339218 +/- 0.02134446 (0.86%) (init = 2)
    expon:      3.25148164 +/- 0.08379431 (2.58%) (init = 2)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(amplitude, sigma) =  0.939
    C(sigma, expon)     = -0.774
    C(amplitude, expon) = -0.745
```

and generate a plot like this

[image]

Comment: @M Newville, How can I call the parameters amplitude, center, sigma, expon resulting from the best fit? I would like to use them after the fit. Thanks

Comment: `result.params` is a dictionary of the best-fit parameters, each Parameter having a `value` and `stderr` attribute (among others).  So `result.params['amplitude'].value` is the best-fit value for the amplitude, etc.  Check docs (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function for the super gaussian

```
    def super_gaussian(x, amp, x0, sigma):
        rank = 2
        return amp * ((np.exp(-(2 ** (2 * rank - 1)) * np.log(2) * (((x - x0) ** 2) / ((sigma) ** 2)) ** (rank))) ** 2)
```

And then you need to call it with scipy optimize curve fit like this:

```
from scipy import optimize

opt, _ = optimize.curve_fit(super_gaussian, x, y)
vals = super_gaussian(x, *opt)
```

'vals' is what you need to plot, that is the fitted super gaussian function.

This is what you get with *rank=1*:
[image]

*rank=2*:
[image]

*rank=3*:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @M Newville works perfectly for me.

**But be careful !** Parenthesis have been fogotten in the quotient of the exponential in the definition of `super_gaussian` function

```
def super_gaussian(x, amplitude=1.0, center=0.0, sigma=1.0, expon=2.0):
    ...
    return ((amplitude/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma))
            * np.exp(-abs(x-center)**expon / 2*sigma**expon))
```

should be replaced by

```
def super_gaussian(x, amplitude=1.0, center=0.0, sigma=1.0, expon=2.0):
    ...
    return (amplitude/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma))
           * np.exp(-abs(x-center)**expon / (2*sigma**expon))
```

Then the FWHM of the super-gaussian function which writes:

```
FWHM = 2.*sigma*(2.*np.log(2.))**(1/expon)
```

is well calculated and in excellent agreement with the plot.

I am sorry to write this text as an answer. But my reputation score is low to add a comment to M Newville post...

Answer (score -2):

Fitting of y(x)=a *exp(-b *(x-c)**p) to data for parameters a,b,c,p.

The example of numerical calculus below shows an non-iterative method which doesn't require initial guess of parameters.

This in an application of the general principle explained in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

In the present version of the paper the case of Super-Gaussian isn't explicitely treated. It is not necessary to read the paper since the screen copy below shows the calculus in whole details.

Note that the numerical results a,b,c,p can be used as initial values for classical iterative methotds of regression.

[image]

Note:

The linear equation considered is :
[image]

A,B,C,D are the parameters to be computed thanks to linear regression. Numerical values S(k) of the integral are directly computed by numerical integration from the given data (As shown in the above example).

Comment: for a non-linear (or non-linearizable) function where regression is not guaranteed to work and an iterative approach is needed, initial values are REQUIRED, and the solutions cannot be guaranteed to be global.   For some functional forms and datasets, one can iterate over initial values or develop methods to estimate initial values (say, using the location of the peak as the center of a Gaussian), but one is still doing a local search to optimize the values.   Initial values are always required.

Comment: @M Newville. I am not surprized by this kind of argument. This means that the principle of the method of linearization remains misunderstood. What is often supposed to be non-linearizable is somtimes linearizable thanks to a transformation involving a convenient integral equation. With the linear form obtained, no initial values are required for the linear regression. This is a mistake to think that all functions currently supposed to be non-lineaizable are definitively non-linearizable.

Comment: if you have a method to estimate parameter values for Gaussian-like peaks, absolutely use that method.  In fact, if it is a robust python implementation, please consider adding that to that `lmfit` or similar tools - that would be very helpful for many users.  I'm not sure I follow your method (my French is poor). It doesn't look exactly linear to me, but still useful for isolated, low-noise peaks.   Still, for an iterative method and real data, these would be starting values....